# Clark C500Y20 Transmission Oil Leak

Tags: oil-leak

I have an old Clark C500Y20 forklift that has a Transmission Oil Leak. It's from 1972 and have been trying to figure out any easy way to fix it. 
If it sits for 2-3 days, it leak alot but when it's running there's no leaks and the oil level is fine. I'm thinking there is an internal leak, but I don't want to take everything apart.
Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix a leak, the best method is to find the joint/ seal/ fixture that is leaking and repair it. Unfortunately there aren't many alternatives to that process that actually work, and trying something like "stop leak" might have unknown consequences for your 47 year old transmission.